# Viewport height will not work on first page load

Tags: css, wordpress

I want my landing page to have an image on top which would be stretched 100 %. 
If I scroll down I should see the rest of the landing page.

I am using WordPress. And on the beginning of landing page I put this DIV tag, before the remaining landing page content:

```
<div id="top_image_div"></div>
```

And this is the CSS for this DIV:

```
#top_image_div{
    width:100%;
  background: url(http://localhost/webaddress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/zzzzzzzzzzzz.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  padding:0;
  height:100vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I think this vh (vertical height) could be a problem..

The page sometimes loads, sometimes, it doesn't load at all. Or, at first the remaining content is shown, no top image. After refresh, top image is shown.

Is there some alternative to this? How can I make a top section to be a full width and height? 
Please, have mercy, I am just a beginner.

thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest not using `vh` or `vw` as they are not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have noticed it. But what is the workaround?

Comment: Have you tried `html, body, #top_image_div {
height: 100%;
}`

Comment: I put it on top of style.css but no top image div.

Comment: I even tried html, body, #top_image_div { height: 100% !important; }

Comment: Try `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: for what tag? and thank you for helping me.

Comment: For the `#top_image_div` tag

Comment: I guess, #top_image_div,,,, but nothing :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use and it works every time:

```css
#top_image_div {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
.someContainer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .42);
}
```

```html
<div id="top_image_div"></div>
<div class="someContainer">
  Some Content here
</div>
```

You can also do it in a position:relative container and it will only fill up that container.

For example:

```
<div class="top-area">
<div id="top_image_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="someContainer">
  Some Content here
</div>
```

```css
#top_image_div {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
.top-area {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
}
.top-area > .header-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  color: white;
  padding: 15px
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.someContainer {
  padding: 50px 20px;
  min-height; 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-area">
  <div id="top_image_div"></div>
  <div class="header-overlay">Scroll down!</div>
</div>
<div class="someContainer">
  Some Content here
</div>
```

Comment: That pretty much means the url of the file is wrong. Are you sure you have the right amount of `z`s in `http://localhost/webaddress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/zzzzzzzzzzzz.jpg`? Load it in a sepparate tab.

Comment: I even put your link instead of mine... link is fine. it works... :( :( I am lost

Comment: in Object inspector I can change background color for top-area div...  and it is visible. I even put opacity: 0 to it thinking maybe the image is behind... but no...

Comment: There are only two options: 1. a problem with your current local setup. 2. another element rendered above this one. To rule out 2., try to create a fiddle reproducing your problem (copy/paste the html/css) and link the resources. If problem still exists, it's option 2. and i'll help you fix it.

Comment: Andrei you are a miracle! Thank you for your help. For top_image_div I put z-index:7 and the image is shown... and I put header-overlay inside top_image-div.... to get the text over the image... it looks fine... Thank you again!